# javascript skips steps and executes last command only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-scraping

Can someone please help me on the JS scraper coding which I tried to create for a website that uses ASP-like coding...

We use the website to download our latest Software Training Manuals, and there are more than 50 Manuals which we have to download by clicking on each item every time. Download Managers won't work, as these PDFs are linked to as __doPostBack() nodes. If I use my coding for one entry only, it works perfectly, but the moment I start batching the command, it skips the `__doPostBack` until the last entry has been reached, and then only executes that one only. I've tried adding a sleep command to slow down the process if that was the issue, but all that did, was to sleep the script for *x*-ms and skip the task of saving the file to loop again.

***Note:*** I'm not too experienced with Javascript, so there may be a few issues with the coding below, and help is always appreciated for educating myself!

I'm using Google Chrome and the Javascript console to run the below script:

```
//Sleep function found on StackOverflow to slow down script for cmdlet
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Node starts with Index 2, so we start there to avoid errors
var i = 2;

while (i <= 15){
    console.log (i);

    // Execute __doPostBack(...) depending on int values
    switch(i){
        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
            var cmdlet = "GridViewLevel3$ctl0" + i + "$lnkFolder3";
            console.log (cmdlet);
            __doPostBack(cmdlet,'');
            sleep(6000);
            break;
        case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15:
            var cmdlet = "GridViewLevel3$ctl" + i + "$lnkFolder3";
            console.log (cmdlet);
            __doPostBack(cmdlet,'');
            sleep(6000);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Error!"); //Handle Exceptions here...
            break;
    };

    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Is the __doPostPack synchronous or asynchronous ?

Comment: never use that kind of sleep... use callbacks to setTimeout instead. 
Otherwise you just kill your processor for nothing

Comment: @mpm I have no idea? How would I find out?

Comment: script not clear kindly put all things that we can help you

Comment: It looks like the `__doPostBack()` function is asynchronous, which would be unsurprising since it's probably where the HTTP transaction and the actual download, occur. I suggest you post it definition.

If `__doPostBack()` was designed so as to enable the use-case you are trying to implement, it should have provision for a callback function, possibly as the second argument  you leave empty here.

See the following link for an introduction to callbacks and asynchronicity

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks

Comment: If there is no provision for callbacks in the existing `__doPostBack()` and if you have no way to modify it accordingly, you'll have to figure out, or get the specifications for, the scheme for the URLs of the PDF files.

I would add that the later would probably be the *first* thing to do, regardless.